# Github: Upload release assets with Bash

Tags: bash, github, release, autorelease

I would like to learn about release asset upload through Github API.
Apart from this
[Github reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/),
I haven't found any recent example.

I created the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

## Make a draft release json with a markdown body
release='"tag_name": "v1.0.0", "target_commitish": "master", "name": "myapp", '
body="This is an automatic release\\n====\\n\\nDetails follows"
body=\"$body\"
body='"body": '$body', '
release=$release$body
release=$release'"draft": true, "prerelease": false'
release='{'$release'}'
url="https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/releases"
succ=$(curl -H "Authorization: token $perstok" --data $release $url)

## In case of success, we upload a file
upload=$(echo $succ | grep upload_url)
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo Release created.
else
    echo Error creating release!
    return
fi

# $upload is like:
# "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:ID/assets{?name,label}",
upload=$(echo $upload | cut -d "\"" -f4 | cut -d "{" -f1)
upload="$upload?name=$theAsset"
succ=$(curl -H "Authorization: token $perstok" \
     -H "Content-Type: $(file -b --mime-type $theAsset)" \
     --data-binary @$theAsset $upload)

download=$(echo $succ | egrep -o "browser_download_url.+?")  
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo $download | cut -d: -f2,3 | cut -d\" -f2
else
     echo Upload error!
fi
```

Of course `perstok`, `owner` and `repo` variables export the personal access token, the owner's name and the repo name and `theAsset` is the asset filename to upload.

Is this the proper way to upload release assets?

Do I need to add an `Accept` header? I found some examples with

```
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.manifold-preview"
```

but they seem outdated to me.

In case of Windows executables is there a specific media (mime) type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an official [answer](https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-11-04-releases-api-is-official):

> during the preview period, you needed to provide a custom media type in the `Accept` header:
>           `application/vnd.github.manifold-preview+json`
>   Now that the preview period has ended, you no longer need to pass this custom media type.

Anyway, while not required, it is recommended to use the following `Accept` header:

```
application/vnd.github.v3+json
```

In this way a specific version of the API is requested, instead of the current one, and an application will keep working in case of future breaking changes.

Comment: Nice catch, more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You have another [example which does not use Accept header in this gist](https://gist.github.com/stefanbuck/ce788fee19ab6eb0b4447a85fc99f447):

```
# Construct url
GH_ASSET="https://uploads.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/releases/$id/assets?name=$(basename $filename)"

curl "$GITHUB_OAUTH_BASIC" --data-binary @"$filename" -H "Authorization: token $github_api_token" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" $GH_ASSET
```

with [`GITHUB_OAUTH_BASIC` being](https://github.com/netj/buildkit/blob/master/upload-github-release-asset#L43)

```
${GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN:?must be set to a github access token that can add assets to $repo} \
${GITHUB_OAUTH_BASIC:=$(printf %s:x-oauth-basic $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN)}
```

A `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` should be universal enough to support any file, without worrying about its MIME.